# Prelude.read: no parse for derived instance of Read

Tags: haskell

I receive the error

```
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

when I run

```
read $ show $ Vector3 1 2 3
```

(Note that `show Vector3 1 2 3` returns `"Vector3 {v3x = 1.0, v3y = 2.0, v3z = 3.0}"`.)

I am using the [AC-Vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/AC-Vector-2.3.2/docs/Data-Vector-V3.html) package as well as an additional

```
{#- LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
deriving instance Read Vector3
```

since the original package doesn't derive Read automatically.

Why is read unable to parse the string?

Comment: Did you give a type signature to the result of the `read` or otherwise constrain its type correctly? Otherwise it might be defaulting to some other type.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam To echo Ganesh here, if you've tried that in GHCi then it defaulted the `Read a => a` constraint into `()`! GHCi has much more aggressive defaulting than people expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value `read $ show $ Vector3 1 2 3` is polymorphic: it has type `Read a => a` and without something to constrain `a`, the compiler won't choose `Vector3` as you expect.

This works for me with `AC-Vector-2.3.2`:

```
read $ show $ Vector3 1 2 3 :: Vector3
```

Your specific symptoms are triggered by the result type being defaulted to some different type. I can reproduce your runtime failure with no type signature on GHC 7.8.3 with `-XExtendedDefaultRules`, which is probably because it defaults `a` to `()`.

Surprisingly GHC 7.6.3 behaves differently and I get an compile time error about an ambiguous type variable instead.

Comment: Were you doing that ambiguous `read` directly in GHCi or in a file? The former has default option `-XExtendedDefaultRules` which gives an unannotated `read "..."` the type `()`, but in a file that is not the case and you get ambiguity.

Comment: I tried in GHCi with and without `ExtendedDefaultRules`

Comment: With `ExtendedDefaultRules`, `read $ show $ Vector3 1 2 3` gives me the no parse, without it gives me ambiguity. This with GHCi 7.8.3.

Comment: I was using 7.6.3 - I get the same results as you with 7.8.3 and I've also checked again with 7.6.3. That's interesting - I wasn't aware of any expected differences between the two.